# How to create shields-like badges with bootstrap?

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, badge, shields.io

You probably know shield badges (from [shields.io](https://shields.io/)).

They are dynamically created svg images of **two types**:

#### 1. Value Badges

```html
<img src="https://img.shields.io/badge/value-5555ff">
```

[image]

#### 2. Key-Value Badges

```html
<img src="https://img.shields.io/badge/key-value-5555ff">
```

[image]

---

They are great, however, there are **two problems** with them:

- They are an extra dependency (no badges if shields.io is down)
- For every badge we have an additional http request (long loading time)

Let's say I am already using **bootstrap** in my project (self-hosted to minimize dependencies). How can I create those two types of badges dynamically with bootstrap?

*(I also use PHP, so a `badge($name, $value, $color)` function would be amazing)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The very basic OOP approach would look like:

```
<?php

class Badge
{

    // colors
    const COLOR_RED = '#f00';
    const COLOR_YELLOW = '#ff0';
    const COLOR_BLUE = '#55f';

    // badges
    const BADGE_PRIMARY = 'bg-primary';
    const BADGE_SECONDARY = 'bg-secondary';
    const BADGE_SUCCESS = 'bg-success';
    // etc

    // icons
    const ICON_FOO = 'icon-foo';
    const ICON_BAR = 'icon-bar';
    const ICON_BAZ = 'icon-baz';


    private $valueColour = Badge::COLOR_BLUE;
    private $badge = Badge::BADGE_SECONDARY;

    private $key = null;
    private $value = [];


    public function reset()
    {
        $this->valueColour = Badge::COLOR_BLUE;
        $this->badge = Badge::BADGE_SECONDARY;
        $this->key = null;
        $this->value = null;

        return $this;
    }

    public function setKey(string $key)
    {
        $this->key = $key;
        return $this;
    }


    public function addValue(string $value, $optionalIcon = null)
    {
        $icon = (!is_null($optionalIcon)) ? "<span class='some-icon-library {$optionalIcon}'></span> " : '';
        $this->value[] = $icon . $value;
        return $this;
    }


    public function setValueColour($colour)
    {
        $this->valueColour = $colour;
        return $this;
    }

    public function build()
    {
        if (is_null($this->value)) {
            echo 'Error: no value';
            return false;
        } else {
            if (!is_array($this->value)) {
                echo 'A value should be an array';
                return false;
            }
        }
        $value = implode(' | ', $this->value);
        if (is_null($this->key) || trim($this->key) == '') {
            echo "<span class='badge text-white p-0'><span class='py-1 px-2 rounded' style='background: {$this->valueColour};'> {$value}</span></span>";
        } else {
            echo "<span class='badge text-white p-0'>
                        <span class='{$this->badge} py-1 px-2 rounded-left'>{$this->key}</span>
                        <span class='py-1 px-2 rounded-right' style='background:{$this->valueColour};'>{$value}</span>
                      </span>";
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

So you can use it in your code by:

```
$badge = new Badge();


// default
$badge
    ->setKey('Basic Key')
    ->addValue('Basic value')
    ->build();

// incorrect
$badge
    ->reset()
    ->setValueColour(Badge::COLOR_RED)
    ->build();

// w/out key
$badge
    ->reset()
    ->addValue('Without key')
    ->setValueColour(Badge::COLOR_RED)
    ->build();

// some sample
$badge
    ->reset()
    ->setKey('Some Key')
    ->addValue('Some value')
    ->setValueColour(Badge::COLOR_RED)
    ->build();

// value(s) with some icons
$badge
    ->reset()
    ->setKey('Another key')
    ->addValue('Yet another value', Badge::ICON_FOO)
    ->addValue('Even more', Badge::ICON_BAR)
    ->addValue('Last but not least')
    ->setValueColour(Badge::COLOR_YELLOW)
    ->build();
```

Note 0: Of course it's rather POC than an exact solution, so you need to polish it by yourself ;)

Note 1: As newest Bootstrap doesn't use any icon set by default, *icons* are dummy so you need to fix it to use with your chosen icon set or just by custom CSS styling.

Note 2: We do not use any setter for value as we want to make usage of array, therefore use `addValue()` to get pipe-separated values.

Answer (score 1):

### Bootstrap Badges HTML

#### 1. Bootstrap Value Badges

```html
<span class="badge text-white p-0"><span class="py-1 px-2 rounded" style="background:#5555ff;">value</span></span>
```

#### 2. Bootstrap Key-Value Badges

```html
<span class="badge text-white p-0 m-1"><span class="bg-secondary py-1 px-2 rounded-left">key</span><span class="py-1 px-2 rounded-right" style="background:#007bff;">value</span></span>
```

In both cases, just replace `#5555ff` with the color of your badge, `value` and `key` with your data.

---

**This is how they look:**

[image]

---

### Dynamic Bootstrap Badges with PHP

This function simply returns the HTML of above and inserts the color, key and value accordingly.

```php
function badge($key, $value, $color="5555ff") {
  if ($key == "")
    return '<span class="badge text-white p-0"><span class="py-1 px-2 rounded" style="background:#' . $color . ';">' . $value . '</span></span>';

  return '<span class="badge text-white p-0"><span class="bg-secondary py-1 px-2 rounded-left">' . $key . '</span><span class="py-1 px-2 rounded-right" style="background:#' . $color . ';">' . $value . '</span></span>';
}
```

You can then call the `badge()` function in the following ways:

```php
// value-badge with the default color (here: #5555ff)
echo badge("", "value");

// value-badge with a custom color (here: yellow)
echo badge("", "value", "ffff00");

// key-value-badge with the default color
echo badge("key", "value");

// key-value-badge with a custom color (here: green)
echo badge("key", "value", "00ff00");
```

---

**Resources**

- [Bootstrap badges documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/components/badge/)
- I also created a [gist on GitHub](https://gist.github.com/finnmglas/702bfe8d3355bb016c4d08ecaefcc1f0) if you are interested in that.

Comment: Cool snippet, but why won't you do it OOP adding more features, like icons, different (selectable) colours etc? (according to shields.io style)

Comment: @biesior Nice idea! I kept it very minimal as that is all I needed... Feel free to answer this question with your code - I will accept the best answer and if that is yours, I will accept yours ^^